# FTP issues after installing DD-WRT

Tags: ftp, dd-wrt

I have recently installed DD-WRT on my D-Link DIR-615 router (rev. D3). Everything seems fine but I cannot connect to some (most) FTP servers anymore. Any ideas what can cause this issue?

--

Passive/active doesn't make a difference.

I've discovered something interesting. I've set up a port range forwarding `1024-65535 | Both | 192.168.1.131` for the testing purposes. After that I have enabled or disabled (it doesn't really matters it seems) the UPnP service and it let me connect to FTP but just for a few seconds.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Here is a little tip. Just by reading the about page at the link near the search bar at the top, you get a badge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old topic, but someone might still find my solution useful: update your firmare. DD-WRT provides updated versions and the last one I could find here http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/other-downloads?path=others%2Feko%2FBrainSlayer-V24-preSP2%2F works. I can finally use FTP.

Comment: Are you using the same router? What version of DD-WRT do you currently have? I've managed to use SFTP and SSH all this time but would be nice to be able to access FTP again :)

Comment: Not using the same router, but I had the same problem on my TP Link. Since last night I use this one:

`DD-WRT v24-sp2 (06/23/14) std
(SVN revision 24461)`

FTP works.

Comment: Awesome. Just upgraded to the same version (for my D-Link DIR 615d) and it works. Thank you fellow romanian!

Comment: You are very welcome, @Andrei!

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you're experiencing an issue with passive mode and these sites. As I understand it the ftp site makes a connection back to you, perhaps dd-wrt's firewall is blocking these back connections to your ftp client upon connecting?

If you run the command `netstat -an` on your dd-wrt box you'll likely see TCP connections waiting.

Comment: I have disabled the SPI Firewall but the problem still occurs. I don't have much experience with DD-WRT but I suppose I'd have to connect through SSH to run that command, right?

Comment: I run the command through web interface and I've got the following (one of the many similar lines, just the port seems different): `tcp  0  0 router_ip:80   local_ip:51773    TIME_WAIT`

Comment: @Andrei - try to ftp to one of the sites that wasn't working and then run that command. See if the IP address of the ftp site shows up with a `TIME_WAIT`.

Comment: I'm seeing just the internal IP's here unfortunately.

Comment: It's not really relevant what the websites are I think. One of them is hosted at MediaTemple and everything worked fine until yesterday when I installed DD-WRT.

Comment: @Andrei - sorry you'd be correct, I didn't realize that it was working and then stopped when you installed DD-WRT. So it would definitely seem to be an issue with it. Let me dig a bit more.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that it dies at Connecting FTP data socket as CuteFTP says. As far as I read it might be related to open ports

Comment: @Andrei - just to confirm that it's definitely the DD-WRT box could you directly connect your computer to the internet and try ftp'ing directly?

Comment: @Andrei - what version of the firmware are you using too?

Comment: Just tested it and everything works fine without router, the latest version of firmware - DD-WRT v24-sp2 (03/25/13) std

Comment: Any ideas I can try it out? Or should I restore it to the stock firmware as this problem is quite important.

Answer (score 0):

I've also experienced the same problem with FTP getting stuck, in my case at retrieving directory listing. After a lot of fiddling I was only able to make it work again by forwarding all ports to my computer's IP connected to the router while also disabling SPI Firewall.

Being unsatisfied with this workaround I followed @conualfy 's advice and updated to a newer firmware. I can confirm the FTP is now working perfectly without further fiddling after upgrading the firmware.

- In my case the router is a Linksys WRT160NL and my current firmware is DD-WRT v24-sp2 (12/22/14)